# Restore ActionBar style or Theme

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

If i do that in a Fragment inside FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //inflate menu

    //change actionBar
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.menu_icons_alerts);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

How can I restore the default Style / theme of actionBar ?

Thx in advanced!